# Something like which for libraries

Tags: libraries, shared-library

I am trying to use two opencv versions on my computer and I am trying to tell my system to use the most recent one that I compiled and installed locally.

I included the install folder in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and now want to check in which order my system can find opencv 2.4.8 (installed from apt-get) and opencv 3.0 (compiled). Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 1):

To check which library the app is using use ldd

ldd /path/to/application

also read up on ldconfig.

Comment: Python does barely use other libraries when started, but it can load python bindings for Opencv for example at runtime. I need to know why it is still loading the older version.